# Use autoId from array to get firebase data, save to another array then use later

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an array which will always have 4 different autoId's (it grabs 4 at random from a node on firebase) - it is the randomKeyArray shown in the image:

[image: image of array]]

I would like to use the autoIDs from the randomKeyArray to get further information from firebase (users full name and profileImageUrl) set these in separate arrays (names, profileImages and namesWithUrl) so that i can use them later on.

I would like the randomKeyArray[0] to correspond to names[0], profileImages[0], namesWithUrl[0] and the same with 1,2,3 etc.

Right now, the names, profileImages and namesWithUrl arrays are empty and I'm not sure why - would appreciate any help :)

```
// the arrays are stored outside the viewDidLoad
var randomKeyArray = [String]()
var names = [String]()
var profileImages = [String]()
var namesWithUrl = [String : String]()

//EDIT: this for loop is where i get the random autoId's for the myKeyArray
for _ in 0...3 { //will iterate four times
    let count = self.myKeyArray.count //get the number of elements
    let randomInt = Int.random(in: 0..<count) //get a random index for the array
    let randomUserKey = self.myKeyArray[randomInt]
    self.randomKeyArray.append(randomUserKey)
    self.myKeyArray.remove(at: randomInt) //remove that object so it's not selected again              
}

print(self.myKeyArray)

//for loop is inside a function    
for i in 0..<self.randomKeyArray.count {
     let thisUserKey = self.randomKeyArray[i]
     self.ref.child("users").child(thisUserKey).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
          let name = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "fullname").value as! String
          let profileImageUrl = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "profileImageUrl").value as! String
          self.names.append(name)
          self.profileImages.append(profileImageUrl)
          self.namesWithUrl[name] = profileImageUrl
          //self.currIds.append(self.randomKeyArray)
     })
 }
```

Let me know if you need any more info!

EDIT:

I have added the for loop which i get the autoId for the randomKeyArray - I have also tried get the name and profile image when the randomUserKey is called in the first for loop but the arrays still show 0 values